# jQuery .wrap issue

Tags: jquery

How would I go about using the jQuery `.wrap` method to wrap a span around text in an element?

Here is the code I am working with so far:

```
$.each(childElements, function(i, val) {
            $(childElements[i]).wrap("<span class='' id='child_element_" + i + "' />");
        });
```

I want to wrap that span around the text that is in my childElements array (the childElements array contains tags such as `<a>`, `<b>` and `<i>`

Comment: You code looks just fine .. is there a problem ? (running example at http://jsfiddle.net/Uhq8P/)

Comment: Well here is what I need to accomplish (code is updated above)... I am grabbing some original text from an onclick event when a user clicks on an element on the screen. It takes the original text and throws it into a modal window that the user can view. My script needs to loop through each child element and replace that child element with the span...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) (If I understand what you want to do correctly).

```
$.each(childElements, function(i, val) {
   $(childElements[i]).wrapInner("<span class='' id='child_element_" + i + "' />");
});
```

It will create `<span>` elements and wrap them around the content of each of your `childElements`.

For example, `<b>Foo</b>` will become `<b><span class='' id='child_element_0'>Foo</span></b>`.